# how to detect browser print (ctrl+p) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a button on my page called `"Print"`. clicking on which will trigger a jQuery function.

I need to call the same jQuery function when user hits `Alt+f+p` or `ctrl+p`

How do I do that?

I tried to do that with `matchMedia` but no luck

```
 if (window.matchMedia('print').matches) {
        alert("print using browser");
    }
```

Comment: The OP has not tried **anything** @aoeu ... Just listen for keyup handlers...

Comment: Are you popping up a new window to print instead of using CSS Print Media? Have you tried listening to key presses? Did that fail?

Comment: That if statement only happens once, you'd need to use it either on an interval or after some event.

Comment: You could use jQuery Hotkeys: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146877/how-to-detect-browser-print-altp-using-jquery#comment31827537_21146877 @BumbleBee

Comment: it's not fair to downvote without giving a proper explanation.

Comment: I did... please read @BumbleBee :-)

Comment: i wrote I tried to handle it with 'matchMedia'.  don't you see that. still u wrote 'has not tried anyting'.

Comment: this is certainly discouraging and misusing downvote.

Comment: @BumbleBee I do think your question is poorly asked and doesn't show enough due dilligence, the snippet you showed could not possibly work. Please show a real attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a standard way to do that as far as I know.

IE and FF offer own function calls,

In **IE** there are the nonstandard window.onBeforePrint() and window.onAfterPrint() event listeners. There isn't a non-IE way to do it that I know of, however.

**Firefox** 6 now supports beforeprint and afterprint
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Printing#Detecting_print_requests

A universally working solution might be to just listen for `CMD+P`.